Why doesn't the exe see the library properly?
I'm using custom tkinter for a project, I'm almost finished and I've started building .exe files.
when I run the program in visual studio, it works flawlessly but when I try the .exe, it returns this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RandMapGenPy.py", line 14, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CTkListbox'

I've used this command to build the .exe
python -m PyInstaller --onefile RandMapGenPy.py --hidden-import CTkListbox  -i dice.ico -n "MapRoller" -w

Here are the libraries I've used:
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog, Toplevel
from tkinter import filedialog
#import TKinterModernThemes as TKMT
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import CTkCheckBox
from customtkinter import *
from CTkListbox import *
from customtkinter.windows.widgets import CTkLabel, CTkOptionMenu#, CTkListbox


General note: from anything import * is bad juju; it means one can't determine from textual analysis of a module alone where a given dependency is supposed to come from. Less room for error when you get rid of the wildcards and either qualify the references (modulename.membername) or make the imports explicit (from modulename import membername)

Apart from doing what @CharlesDuffy mentioned, I also think you should import your CTkListBox before importing anything from it.

I've tried both of you suggestions but the result is the same

you may try to run without --onefile and it will create folder with all modules which it adds to .exe - if there is no CTkListbox then it could have problem to find it - so it didn't add it to file created with --onefile. It may need to read documentation for pyinstaller to see if there are other option to add this module. OR maybe CTkListbox needs some other modules to work and you have to add them also with options.

This is definitely not the correct way, but it'll work, after completing a time-taking task. Not the best option. Paste the code of CTkListbox, (ctk_listbox.py). Change all the imports — like in ctk_listbox.py, import customtkinter has been used, change it to from customtkinter import * or whatever you want. Since you're using VS Code, it will be easier to find where customtkinter.whatever has been used. Then, change it to the specific import.
